# Modify the stored struct data to other structure

Tags: ios, swift, file, struct

```
struct myStruct1: Codable {
    var field1: String
    var field2: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case field1 = "field1"
        case field2 = "field2"
    }

//Storing the Values to the local file,
//[{"field1":"someValue1","field2":"someValue2"},{"field1":"someValue3","field2":"someValue4"}]

//Now i changed the struct to store an additional field as,

struct myStruct1: Codable {
var field1: String
var field2: String
var field3: String
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case field1 = "field1"
    case field2 = "field2"
    case field3 = "field3"
}
```

From now there will be three field values will be stored to the file, but for the data already stored will have just two fields and i need to update the
    newly added `field3` with default value `someValue0` to the stored data in the file,
    how can i achieve this.

Am I clear?

Comment: Override init with decoder, and if there if no field3, set it to your default value. Then replace your value in your local file.

Comment: will field3 existence be optional ??? or won't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it optional

```
 var field3: String?
```

And assign later or better write `init` and give it the value

```
struct myStruct1: Codable {
  var field1: String
  var field2: String
  var field3: String
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case field1 = "field1"
      case field2 = "field2"
      case field3 = "field3"
  }

      init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
          let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
          field1 = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .field1)
          field2 = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .field2)
          field3 = "someValue0"
    }
}
```

---

If the filed3 would exists then do

```
field3 = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .field3) ?? ""
```

Comment: `try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .field1)`, `Double.self`? Really? Also, you don't check if `field3` exists, has a value and if not, set the default one?

Comment: @Larme it's a copy paste issue , also don't get from op if field3 will be there as optional or not , so added both ways